# SyncAdapter process killed when swiped from recents

Tags: android, android-service, android-syncadapter, kill-process, android-recents

I am trying to create SyncAdapter running background operation (without foreground notification).

It is working, except the case when activity (task) which triggered `ContentResolver.requestSync(...)` is swiped away from recent applications. In that case process is killed and `onPerformSync(...)` is not finished.

I know, this is expected Android behavior, but in regular `Service` I would set

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

or maybe use

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    restartSynchronization();
}
```

to retry synchronization, but this is not working in the SyncAdapterService.

How can I ensure synchronization continues/retry after activity is swiped away from recent applications?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found out, that `onStartCommand()` is not called for `SyncAdapterService` which makes sense due to this service is just for returning `Binder`. But still I would expect `onTaskRemoved()` is.

Answer (score 0):

After some reseach I found out, that `onTaskRemoved(...)` is called only when `startService(...)` is called and not when someone only binds to it.

So I did work around by starting service in `onBind(...)` and stopping it and its process in `onUnbind(...)` methods.

This is final code:

```
public class SyncAdapterService extends Service {
private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
private static MySyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
        if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
            sSyncAdapter = new MySyncAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    /*
     * Rescheduling sync due to running one is killed on removing from recent applications.
     */
    SyncHelper.requestSyncNow(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    /*
     * Start service to watch {@link @onTaskRemoved(Intent)}
     */
    startService(new Intent(this, SyncAdapterService.class));

    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    /*
     * No more need watch task removes.
     */
    stopSelf();

    /*
     * Stops current process, it's not necessarily required. Assumes sync process is different
     * application one. (<service android:process=":sync" /> for example).
     */
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
}
```